# Generating Table & Cell in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, arrays, json, xamarin

I have a problem generating a table view from array json data that I have get.

I have completed of getting and saving the json data in array form, but the problem I facing is that I cannot load them into my table.

Below is my code,

```
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
        {
            string json = response.Content;
            Console.WriteLine(json);

            List<PostInfo> curTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PostInfo>>(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < curTest.Count; i++)
            {
                PostInfo t1 = curTest[i];
                arraydata.Add(t1.title.rendered);   
            }
            array1 = arraydata.ToArray();

        });

        UITableView _table;
        _table = new UITableView    
        {
            Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 20, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height - 20),
            Source = new TableSource(array1)
        };
        View.AddSubview(_table);
```

The table returns a blank page when I trying to put the array1 as my TableSource. And I believe that if the array1 has nothing in the array once it out from the client.ExecuteAsync.

Can someone guide me how to generate TableView based on array get from the json data?

Comment: When is client.ExecuteAsync been called?

Comment: I calling it in ViewDidLoad().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that when you try assign data source to your table view the array is still empty. Short term solution would be - re-assign datasource in async operation closure and dont forget to call TableView.ReloadData(). But it's not the prettiest solution. I would suggest you MVVMCross - You write your Core project with business logic and then you create platform project and use bindings to bind say Datasource to a collection of items. You can find tutorials with source code on the internet. There are plenty of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I will look into MVVM Cross in Xamarin.

As for the short term solution, I need to move the tableview in the client.ExecuteAsync and set the array data in the table source?

Comment: @JmingL , I guess TableView creation can be left as it is now, but try re-assign it's Source in client.ExecuteAsync and then call TableView.ReloadData()

Comment: Call ReloadData should be enough. Also ViewDidLoad might not be the best place because it is not called again. Better move your call to ViewWillAppear if the data change frequently.

Comment: Hi Sergey, Thank you very much for guiding, I managed to display my data in Listview using MVVM structure. 

same codes, but with listView.ItemSources = array data

Comment: @JmingL Pleased to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your view doesn't realise that the source has changed. Big chance that if you get it working and change the properties of objects in your array, your view also won't know its data has changed.

Take a look at this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Basically what this interface does is tell the view or binding that something has changed. This way the view knows not only to update, if you are smart about it it only updates 1 value, the one that changed.

Now for your current problem, how to fix it with this interface? Simply change your array to an ObservableCollection -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

An ObservableCollection is like a List but it already has the INotifyPropertyChanged interface implemented.

Comment: Yes, observablecollection is cool. But it's not a silver bullet. I think the best solution here would be - separate business logic from UI and then here ObservableCollection comes. BTW, mvvmcross adepts use observable collections as they are easy to bind to

Comment: You are absolutely right. This isn't what OP asked for however. He will figure out eventually that his structure is wrong, there is no way you can tell someone, he has to find out by himself :)

Comment: I am new in developing in iOS, but is it a better start to develop the application from MVVM environment? Currently, I am learning on the basic features of the iOS such as manipulating the data.

Comment: Depends on what the application is for. Maybe you want to use MVC instead.. These are just design philsophies of how you structure will look like. I usually have to find out the hard way why you would want any of them. Its a good idea to get familiar with the flow of your application first: what happens when? How do I switch between pages and what is still in memory after I do? etc. Then figure out the best way to keep your code organised, mvvm would allow you to keep user interface code seperate from business logic, which is why its desireable

Comment: MVC is what Apple gives us. It's a little bit different from original idea of MVC and has a lot of drawbacks, but still. You can also take a look at VIPER - advanced pattern. But i strongly believe that xamarin along with mvvm can help one to achieve great goals if you keep your logic in one core project and platform UI implementation in other projects. Try use .net capabilities as much as possible :)

Comment: Noted, and thanks for the suggestions. I will look more into it.